# Pythonic way for the following code

Tags: python

I have a python dict

```
a = {
     "Ram":(20,"Male"),
     "Shyam":(22,"Male"),
     "Shruti":(19,"Female"),
    }
```

I want to check whether a name is present in the dict as key and return age based on it otherwise name. So I have written the following function for it

```
def func(val ):
   if val in a:
     return ( a[val][ 0 ], True ) # Return age and key in dict?
   return ( val, False )
```

Can I write this in a better way? A one liner or something?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want a function that sometimes returns a person's age and sometimes returns the person's name?

Comment: Often a good exercise is to think "If this were in a statically typed function, how would I declare my return value".  If you have disparately different types from different branches, it's often a good idea to rethink the problem.

Comment: @user2357112 : The example is just hypothetical.

Comment: Use pandas for tabular data like this.

Comment: Please keep in mind that a one liner doesn't necessarily mean a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the function `get(key, default)` from dictionaries:

```
def f(val):
    result = a.get(val, False)
    return (result[0], True) if result else (val, result)
```

- `get(key, default)` returns the correct value if `key` is in the dicitonary and returns `default value if it is not.

Comment: I have heard that searching a key in a dict like "if key in dict" is O(1). What about get?

Comment: `get()` is similar to accessing to a `key`, but it also handles the exception that is raised if the `key` is not in the dicitonary and returns a default value instead.

Comment: @user3230698: Also O(1). Pretty much as long as you don't call `keys` or iterate over the dict to find an element, any operation that inserts or locates an entry in a dict is O(1).

Comment: @user3230698 yes, it's `O(1)`. That's the thing that makes dictionaries interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any point in returning `val` when you passed it in, especially if you were hoping for a completely different object (the age), so I suggest one of these alternatives:

```
def func(val):
    if val in a:
        return a[val][0]
    return None
```

Which could be simplified to (with the exception of returning `False` instead of `None`:

```
def func(val):
    return val in a and a[val][0]
```

Or

```
def func(val):
    return a[val][0]    # raises KeyError if not found
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to make your data structure more informative, to use the `get()` method on the dicts, and to abandon the idea of returning a tuple. Regarding the latter, it's not clear why you need the extra boolean value.

```
persons = {
    'Ram'    : { 'age' : 20, 'sex' : 'Male' },
    'Shyam'  : { 'age' : 22, 'sex' : 'Male' },
    'Shruti' : { 'age' : 19, 'sex' : 'Female' },
}

def get_age(name):
    return persons.get(name, {}).get('age')

names = 'Ram Shruti Foo'.split()

print map(get_age, names)  # [20, 19, None]
```